# Bootstrap Navbar content stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap newbie here. I've only today started using Bootstrap to develop a website with, but something's going on that I can't figure out. I am using the following code to create my navigation:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav uppercase bold">
                <li><a href="#">Projecten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Over</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" rel="home" href="#"><img src="images/97x30.png" style="margin-top:-4px;"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The idea is that there's a set of links aligned to the left, and a logo is displayed aligned to the right. Now I have noticed that this works fine as long as the browser window size is larger than 768px (where the bootstrap css still assigns a width to .container) but when the window becomes smaller (and the .container class no longer has a width, I believe), the links on aligned to the left of the navbar start stacking vertically, instead of horizontally.

The uppercase and bold classes in the ul are included in my custom css, to style the links.

If I were to guess, it has something to do with the "block" alignment or perhaps the .container becoming too small to fit the links horizontally, but I am unable to figure this out, and could not find a similar problem on the web.

I figure this is probably something very simple and makes me look  stupid, but I hope you can help. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: its a feature of bootstrap that allow you to make responsive design where the content of the page get settled down as per the screen size and prevent you to get the scroll bar.

Comment: I see how that makes sense as a feature, however the size of the links should permit some horizontal stacking before it starts stacking them vertically. Is it possible to change the CSS to allow this?

Comment: Yup! Totally possible. Edit the `@media` queries where `768px` is used as the `max-width`. You'll find those in the `bootstrap.css` file

Comment: hey man, welcome to Stack Overflow! The thing about Bootstrap is that it's build to be mobile friendly so the navbar will collapse on resolutions <= 768px http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar You can configure bootstrap to stop doing this using their customizer http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Thanks for the quick help guys. I understand what Bootstrap is trying to do. Is there a way to keep the content (links & logo) in the navbar aligned horizontally at all times? I'm asking because the content could fit horizontally in a 320px wide navbar (which I believe is the smallest screen size I should be prepared for).

Comment: @Dennis: you can [disable responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive), though that'll affect everything, not just the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add CSS like this to prevent it from stacking..

```
.navbar-nav {
    min-width:360px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/114462